# Reduce DOM updates vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, rendering

I want to dynamically get and display a list when the button is clicked. I have this code:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  const outputContainer = document.getElementById('output');

  while (outputContainer.firstChild) {
    outputContainer.removeChild(outputContainer.lastChild);
  }

  arr.map((el) => {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const txt = document.createTextNode(el);
    listItem.appendChild(txt);
    outputContainer.appendChild(listItem);
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Get list</button>
<ul id="output" />
```

But every time I click the button the whole ul element is re-rendered although its content doesn't change. Is there any way to re-write this code somehow using vanilla JS to avoid unnecessary DOM updates?
P.S: List can be different every time cause it will be coming from an API

Comment: Is your button within a form? Buttons are `type="submit"` by default, and thus submit the form, refreshing the screen. Try using `<button id="button" type="button">Get list</button>` instead.

Comment: no, it doesn't refresh the whole page, I just can see in my dev tools that the ul element is re-painted in dom

Answer (score 1):

If you need to overwrite your list items every time your button is clicked, you could use the `Element.replaceChildren()` method ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren)).

It saves you the trouble of having to manually remove each child before adding new ones.

I rewrote a bit of your code but the logic is the same. Notice how you don't need the while loop anymore.

As far as I know, the UL will still re-render since your're updating (replacing) its children. You could implement a comparison between the previous and next list elements and stop the function early if both lists contain the same data, thus preventing unnecessary renders.

```js
// get the output UL element
const outputContainer = document.getElementById("output");

const onButtonClick = () => {
  const arr = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]; // use of element.replaceChildren() to clear the list and append new items
  outputContainer.replaceChildren(
    ...arr.map((listItemText) => {
      const listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.textContent = listItemText;
      return listItem;
    })
  );
};

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
```

```html
<button id="button">Get list</button>
<ul id="output" />
```